# create linked list in React - Expanding on the React Tic-Tac-Toe Tutorial

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to expand on the official react Tic-Tac-Toe tutorial: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#completing-the-game by creating a linked list to search for the win condition. However, I am having issues accessing the information. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? I keep getting undefined with my console.log on line 138

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';

function Square(props) {
return (
\<button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}\>
{props.value}
{props.rightmiddle}
{props.righttop}
{props.rightbottom}
{props.lefttop}
{props.leftbottom}
{props.top}
{props.bottom}
\</button\>
);
}

class Board extends React.Component {  
renderSquare(i) {
return (
\<Square
value={this.props.squares\[i\]}
rightmiddle = {null}
righttop = {null}
rightbottom = {null}
leftmiddle = {null}
lefttop = {null}
leftbottom = {null}
top = {null}
bottom = {null}
onClick={() =\>
this.props.onClick(i)
}
/\>
);
}

    forloop(x){
      const numcolumns = 3;
      const options = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < numcolumns; i++) {
        options.push(this.renderSquare(i + x));
      }
      return (
        <div className="board-row">
        {options}
        </div>
        )
    }
      
    render() {
      const numrows = 3;
      const linklistTRow = [];
      const linklistBRow = [];
      const linklistMRow = [];
      const rows = [];
      for(let i = 0; i < numrows; i++)
        {
          rows.push(this.forloop(i*numrows));
          if (i === 0) { linklistTRow.push(rows[0])};
          if (i === 1) { linklistMRow.push(rows[1])};
          if (i === 2) { linklistBRow.push(rows[2])};
        };
      return (
        <div> {rows} </div>
      );
    }

}

class Game extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
history: \[{
squares: Array(9).fill(null),
}\],
stepNumber: 0,
xIsNext: true,
};
}
handleClick(i) {
const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);
const current = history\[history.length - 1\];
const squares = current.squares.slice();
if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares\[i\]){
return;
}
squares\[i\] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
this.setState({
history: history.concat(\[{
squares: squares,
}\]),
stepNumber: history.length,
xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
});
}

    jumpTo(step) {
      this.setState({
        stepNumber: step,
        xIsNext: (step % 2) === 0,
      });
    }
    
    render() {
      const history = this.state.history;
      const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
      const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);
      
      const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
        const desc = move ?
          'Go to move #' + move :
          'Go to game start';
        return (
          <li key={move}>
            <button onClick = {() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}
            </button>
          </li>
        );
      });
      
      let status;
      if (winner) {
        status = 'Winner: ' + winner;
      }
      else {
        status = 'Next player: ' + (this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O');
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="game">
          <div className="game-board">
            <Board 
              squares = {current.squares}
              onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}
              log = {console.log(this.props.value)}
              />
          </div>
          <div className="game-info">
            <div>{status}</div>
            <ol>{moves}</ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

}

// ========================================

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(\<Game /\>);

function calculateWinner(squares) {
const lines = \[
\[0, 1, 2\],
\[3, 4, 5\],
\[6, 7, 8\],
\[0, 3, 6\],
\[1, 4, 7\],
\[2, 5, 8\],
\[0, 4, 8\],
\[2, 4, 6\],
\];
for (let i = 0; i \< lines.length; i++) {
const \[a, b, c\] = lines\[i\];
if (squares\[a\] && squares\[a\] === squares\[b\] && squares\[a\] === squares\[c\]) {
return squares\[a\];
}
}
return null;
}
```

I have been trying to use props.value to call the square number (0 to 8) however, this is showing undefined results.

Comment: You don't pass any props to `<Game />`

Comment: So even without using props and simply trying to call value or square.value the result is still undefinec